# Union of multiple lists python

Tags: python, list, union

how to perform union of elements of dict objects of all sublists of a list in python:
ex:

```
[
 [
  {'a':'b'}
 ],
 [
 { 'c':'d'} 
 ]
]
```

element at pos 0 in sublist 1 should union with element at pos 0 in sublist 2 Ex OUTPUT:

```
  [
     [
      {
       'a':'b',
       'c':'d'
      } 

     ]
    ]
```

Comment: Will all sublists be of the same size?

Comment: @Jason Yes , every sublist will be of same size

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` up the lists and `merge_dicts()`:

```
def merge_dicts(*args):
    r = {}
    for d in args:
        r.update(d)
    return r

>>> lst = [[{'a':'b'}],[{ 'c':'d'}]]
>>> [merge_dicts(*ds) for ds in zip(*lst)]
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}]
>>> lst = [[{'a':'b'},{1:2}],[{'c':'d'},{3:4}],[{'e':'f'},{5:6}]]
>>> [merge_dicts(*ds) for ds in zip(*lst)]
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}, {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}]
```